# Sliding Right Submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, toggle

I am trying to develop piece of 'sliding right' functionality.

I have a set of main menus `class="menu-heading"` and when clicked on, their corresponding submenu's `class="menu-body"` should slide out to the right. Each of these submenus can be expanded/collapsed to reveal information.

I have been able to develop the expand and collapse of the submenu, but sliding to the right is proving difficult without using jQuery UI

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="menu-heading">
            <label>Top Ten Questions</label>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-body">
            <div>
                <label class="menu-body-heading bold">Question 1</label>
                <label class="visuallyhidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, nesciunt, adipisci consequuntur consectetur praesentium quaerat dolorem mollitia doloremque modi ullam!</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="bold">Question 2</label>
                <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="bold">Question 3</label>
                <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="menu-heading">
            <label>Contact Us</label>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-body">
            <div>
                <label class="bold">Whats your email?</label>
                <label>test@test.com</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="bold">Whats your telephone?</label>
                <label>0000000001</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="menu-heading">
            <label>Products</label>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-body">
            <div>
                <label class="bold">Tables</label>
                <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="bold">Chairs</label>
                <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".menu-body").hide();

$(".menu-heading").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next(".menu-body").slideToggle(400);
});
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/8stR4/1/

I am trying to achieve this **without** jQuery UI

Similar to what i am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2/light/  (when Right is selected from the dropdown)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[A great tutorial for sliding elements](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/)

```
$('#yourDiv').animate({
  marginLeft: parseInt($('#yourDiv').css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ?
    $('#yourDiv').outerWidth() : 0
});
```

Comment: Providing a link as the only part of an answer is a bad practice. See this meta post for why http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Should I delete it and post it as a comment?

Comment: @LCH - Thanks, but do you have a working fiddle based on my example?

Comment: @LCH - Thanks, but 2 issues.. The menus dont appear to be able to be closed, and also, how can the submenu be on the same line height as the main menu.. Its showing below.

Comment: To close the `subMenu`, just animate to `margin-left:0` and `display:none`. You can add a `data-status` attribute to the element, so you can check if it's open/close to apply the current animation. As for the line-height, you should workout your css, and make two columns, one with the headings and the other with the content. By the way, in the HTML, there are many elements that aren't needed, for example the label tag.